# I need to copy the top 10 rows from a table and add it to same table, but id column is primary key??? how can I do this?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to copy the top 50 rows from the table named T_myorders which has 100 rows, and add it to same table, but the id column is primmary key, which is not letting me to do this, and I need the output in such a way when I add the rows to my table the added rows should start the id column with 101,102,103.... instead of again printing same 1,2,3....This one step and another one is,

I should declare two values one is how many top rows I need to copy and another value is how many times it should repeat, say 2, then the 50 rows should repeat two times and id column should be upto 200.
             Can anyone help me in this task.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Please fix your question so it's formatted properly. Add some line-breaks!

Comment: Hey I have edited my question, please have a look.

Comment: When you say "Top 50", you mean the 50 rows with the smallest IDs?

Answer (score 0):

create a temp table 
insert top x records (where x is first input parameter) into temp table using select insert.
find the maximum primary key value, increament it by 1 and store it in a variable primary_key
Declare a cursor to fetch records from temp table

Create a for loop which runs for y times (where y is 2nd parameter)
inside for loop 
open the cursor and read rows
loop
insert the records in to the main table, use primary_key as a primary key
reassign the primary_key = primary_key +1
close loop
close the cursor
close the for loop

Hope this helps. This is just an algorithim which might be helpful

This can be done in a Better way

you can avoid cursor by using below statement 
  create a temp table 
insert top x records (where x is first input parameter) into temp table using select insert.
find the maximum primary key value, store it in a variable primary_key

Create a for loop which runs for y times (where y is 2nd parameter)
inside for loop 
insert into YOUR_TABLE SELECT IDENTITY(int, primary_key ,1) AS id, REST OF COLUMNS from temp table 
reset the primary_key to hold the new value
close loop

Comment: you can avoid cursor by using below statement  <br/>     insert into YOUR_TABLE SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS id, REST OF COLUMNS  from temp table

Answer (score 0):

declare @s1 as int

select @s1=MAX(primary key) from **Table**

insert into **Table**

select top 50 ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by 0 order by f1)+@s1 as pk_id *(instead of primary key)* ,f1,f2,f3 from **Table**